# How do I get local data into a read-only database using dplyr?

Tags: postgresql, dbplyr, wrds

WRDS is a leading provider of research data to academics and other researchers in business and related fields.
WRDS provides a PostgreSQL database, but this is a read-only database.

For some tasks, the inability to write data to the database is very constraining. For example, if I want to run an event study using daily stock returns, I will need to merge my (relatively small) local data set `events` with `crsp.dsf`, which is about 18GB of data.

One option is to maintain my own database with a copy of `crsp.dsf` and write `events` to that database and merge there. But I am looking for an option that allows me to use the WRDS database for this purpose. Unfortunately, there is no way to use `copy_to` or `dbWriteTable`, as the WRDS database is read-only.

Comment: Any updates about this? I posted a similar question here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74187711/join-a-data-frame-or-other-r-object-to-a-table-in-a-read-only-postgresql-datab

Comment: A few months late, but see updated answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more up-to-date answer than the one below is to use the [`copy_inline`](https://dbplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/copy_inline.html) function from the `dbplyr` package, which was added following an [issue](https://github.com/tidyverse/dbplyr/issues/628) filed on this topic.

---

One option is to use something like the following function, which turns a local data frame into a remote data frame using SQL *even when using a read-only connection*.

```
df_to_pg <- function(df, conn) {

    collapse <- function(x) paste0("(", paste(x, collapse = ", "), ")")

    names <- paste(DBI::dbQuoteIdentifier(conn, names(df)), collapse = ", ")

    values <-
        df %>%
        lapply(DBI::dbQuoteLiteral, conn = conn) %>%
        purrr::transpose() %>%
        lapply(collapse) %>%
        paste(collapse = ",\n")

    the_sql <- paste("SELECT * FROM (VALUES", values, ") AS t (", names, ")")

    temp_df_sql <- dplyr::tbl(conn, dplyr::sql(the_sql))
    
    return(temp_df_sql)
}
```

Here is an illustration of the function in use. Function has been tested on PostgreSQL and SQL Server, but will not work on SQLite (due to lack of `VALUES` keyword that works in this way).
I believe it should work on MySQL or Oracle, as these have the `VALUES` keyword.

```r
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(DBI)
   
pg <- dbConnect(RPostgres::Postgres())     

events <- tibble(firm_ids = 10000:10024L,
                 date = seq(from = as.Date("2020-03-14"), 
                            length = length(firm_ids), 
                            by = 1))
events
#> # A tibble: 25 x 2
#>    firm_ids date      
#>       <int> <date>    
#>  1    10000 2020-03-14
#>  2    10001 2020-03-15
#>  3    10002 2020-03-16
#>  4    10003 2020-03-17
#>  5    10004 2020-03-18
#>  6    10005 2020-03-19
#>  7    10006 2020-03-20
#>  8    10007 2020-03-21
#>  9    10008 2020-03-22
#> 10    10009 2020-03-23
#> # … with 15 more rows

events_pg <- df_to_pg(events, pg)
events_pg
#> # Source:   SQL [?? x 2]
#> # Database: postgres [iangow@/tmp:5432/crsp]
#>    firm_ids date      
#>       <int> <date>    
#>  1    10000 2020-03-14
#>  2    10001 2020-03-15
#>  3    10002 2020-03-16
#>  4    10003 2020-03-17
#>  5    10004 2020-03-18
#>  6    10005 2020-03-19
#>  7    10006 2020-03-20
#>  8    10007 2020-03-21
#>  9    10008 2020-03-22
#> 10    10009 2020-03-23
#> # … with more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: This is great! However I am not able to reproduce your example in Oracle. Would you know how to rewrite the function to make it function in Oracle as well? Here is the error message I am getting (shortened to fit the comment):

 Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1617: 42S02: [Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-00903: invalid table name
 
<SQL> 'SELECT *
FROM (SELECT * FROM (VALUES (10000, '2020-03-14 UTC'),
(10001, '2020-03-15 UTC'),
...
(10024, '2020-04-07 UTC') ) AS t ( "firm_ids", "date" )) "q01"
WHERE (0 = 1)'

Comment: @CAJ I don't know. My guess is that it might make sense to tweak the function to return SQL and then (using a small table) tweak the SQL to fit the demands of Oracle's syntax. It looks like the "AS t (" part might be parsed as a table name by Oracle.

Answer (score -1):

Posting for future reference:
This has been added to dplyr
https://dbplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/copy_inline.html