# Can I upload a Python Pandas DataFrame to the WRDS cloud to use in a raw_sql Statement?

Tags: python, wrds

I am using the `wrds` module in Python to extract data from WRDS. In SAS, I can easily upload a local file to the WRDS server to use in a SQL statement on the WRDS server. The code for that is:

```
proc upload data=mydatafile out=mydatafile; run;
```

Is there something similar in Python? I have a Pandas DataFrame called `send_to_crsp` containing tickers and dates that I'd like to use in the `raw_sql` statement below:

```
import pandas as pd
import wrds

db = wrds.Connection()

rets = db.raw_sql('''
                    select a.TIC, a.DATE_FILED0, a.DATE_FILED5, b.date, b.ret
                    from send_to_crsp as a, crsp.dsf as b
                    where a.TIC=b.tic and b.date >= a.DATE_FILED and b.date <= a.DATE_FILED5
                  ''',
                  date_cols = ['DATE_FILED0','DATE_FILED5','date'])
```

Answer (score 0):

WRDS users do not have `CREATE TABLE` or even `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE` privileges, so there are no options to get data into a table on the WRDS PostgreSQL server.

To handle this issue on R (see StackOverflow question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66910165/how-do-i-get-local-data-into-a-read-only-database-using-dplyr)), I basically translate a local data frame into an SQL statement of the following form:

```sql
SELECT * FROM 
    (VALUES (10000, '2012-01-03'), (10001, '2013-02-04')) AS t (permno, date))
```

Using `dplyr` it is easy to make this into a "table" that can be joined with `crsp.dsf`. See `dbplyr::copy_inline()` for a function that does all this (and see [here](https://iangow.github.io/far_book/beaver68.html) for illustrations of the function's use).

Unfortunately, support and documentation for these kinds of data analysis workflows seems much weaker for Python. Perhaps something similar could be made using SQLAlchemy.