# Join a data frame (or other R object) to a table in a read-only Postgresql database?

Tags: r, postgresql, wrds, rpostgres

I have read-only access to a Postgres database. I can not write to the database.

Q. Is there a way to construct and run a SQL query where I join a data frame (or other R object) to a table in a read-only Postgres database?

This is for accessing data from WRDS, https://wrds-www.wharton.upenn.edu/

Here's an attempt at pseudocode

```
#establish a connection to a database
con <- dbConnect( Postgres(), 
          host = 'host.org',
          port = 1234,
          dbname = 'db_name',
          sslmode = 'require',
          user = 'username', password = 'password')

#create an R dataframe (or other object)
df <- data.frame( customer_id = c('a123', 'a-345', 'b0')  )


#write a sql query we will run
sql_query <- "
SELECT t.customer_id, t.* FROM df t
   LEFT JOIN table_name df
      on t.customer_id = df.customer_id
"

my_query_results <- dbSendQuery(con, sql_query)
temp <- dbFetch(res, n = 1)
dbClearResult(res)
my_query_results
```

Note and edit: The example query I provided is intentionally super simple for example purposes.

In my actual queries, there might be 3 or more columns I want to join on, and millions of rows I want to join on.

Comment: A similar question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67291089/can-i-upload-a-python-pandas-dataframe-to-the-wrds-cloud-to-use-in-a-raw-sql-sta/74194662#74194662

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`copy_inline`](https://dbplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/copy_inline.html) function from the `dbplyr` package, which was added following an [issue](https://github.com/tidyverse/dbplyr/issues/628) filed on this topic. See also the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66910165/how-do-i-get-local-data-into-a-read-only-database-using-dplyr).

An example of its use is found [here](https://iangow.github.io/far_book/beaver68.html) and also below.
Before running the code below, run code like this in your R console:

```
Sys.setenv(PGHOST = "wrds-pgdata.wharton.upenn.edu",
           PGPORT = 9737L,
           PGDATABASE = "wrds",
           PGUSER = "YOUR_WRDS_ID",
           PGPASSWORD = "YOUR_WRDS_PASSWORD")
```

Then (assuming you have the `dplyr`, `dbplyr`, and `RPostgres` packages installed) you should be able to copy-paste the following code to check that it works for you. Many more examples can be found [here](https://iangow.github.io/far_book/intro.html).

```r
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(DBI)
library(dbplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

pg <- dbConnect(RPostgres::Postgres(), sslmode='require')

events <- tibble(permno = 14593L,
                 event_desc = c("WWDC 2005 ", "Apple Special Event", 
                                "WWDC 2006"),
                 date = as.Date(c("2005-06-06", "2006-02-28", 
                                  "2006-02-28")))
events_pg <- copy_inline(pg, events)

dsf <- tbl(pg, sql("SELECT * FROM crsp.dsf"))

results <-
  dsf %>%
  inner_join(events_pg, join_by(permno, date)) %>%
  select(permno, date, event_desc, ret, prc) %>%
  collect()

results
#> # A tibble: 3 × 5
#>   permno date       event_desc                 ret   prc
#>    <dbl> <date>     <chr>                    <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1  14593 2005-06-06 "WWDC 2005 "          -0.00837  37.9
#> 2  14593 2006-02-28 "Apple Special Event" -0.0352   68.5
#> 3  14593 2006-02-28 "WWDC 2006"           -0.0352   68.5
```

<sup>Created on 2023-04-23 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

If your join is on a single condition, it can be rewritten using an `in` clause:

In SQL:

```
SELECT customer_id
FROM table_name 
WHERE customer_id in ('a123', 'a-345', 'b0')
```

Programmatically from R:

```
sql_query = sprintf(
  "SELECT customer_id
   FROM table_name 
   WHERE customer_id in (%s)",
  paste(sQuote(df$customer_id, q = FALSE), collapse = ", ")
)
```

Comment: Thanks.  The example query I provided was intentionally super simple for example purposes. 

In my actual example, there might be 3 or more columns I want to join on, and millions of rows I want to join on. .

Comment: Then I think you're out of luck.

Comment: That's what I thought, but I wanted to ask.

Comment: Use `copy_inline` from the `dbplyr` package. If local (R) table is not super large, it should work fine.

Comment: @IanGow very cool! You should post that as an answer!

Comment: @gregor-thomas Thanks for the suggestion. I posted this as an answer.